# .NET MD5 Checksum

Tags: .net, md5, checksum

I'm creating a modular desktop application with agile licensing in a database. I have several ways of preventing hackers from using the application and I want to implement more.

I thought about having the software create its own MD5 checksum and the MD5 checksum of its plugins and then running it against the database to make sure no one has tampered with it.

Would this be a good idea?

The only cons I see is that I'd have to update the database with checksums of the current versions of all the plugins which may be fruitless in the long run having to do this every time there's a version increment. Another con would be the ability of the hacker to intercept the packages or just feed the client what it wants to hear to make it functional.

What do you think?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you considered signing the assembly, and disable all functionality if you cannot verify the assembly identity ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwb8f617.aspx

Comment: Thank you driis I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another con would be the ability of the hacker to intercept the packages or just feed the client what it wants to hear to make it functional.

That's exactly the problem. If you can tamper with it enough to invalidate the hash, you can easily tamper with it enough to return the *valid* hash.

My philosophy is:

- With a little effort you can keep "naturally honest" people honest; very minimal licensing code is required for this.
- It can take a *lot* of effort to even deter those who really want to get around whatever licensing you put in place. The games industry spends a fortune on this, and still seems to suffer enormously from piracy.

I'd spend your time making your product so good that people will want to pay you for it rather than wasting the money of people who *are* paying you for it: they're effectively paying for a "feature" that doesn't help them do their work any faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jon, in the target market that the software is going to pull, I don't see a lot of threats, but as always I think it's good to be cautious. But your philosophy is great. One of the other countermeasures put in place is a session system which controls the functionality of the software having that half of the software is server-side. So the client wouldn't be able to work by itself. I guess this will suffice.

Comment: @Theveloper: The thing to remember is that caution costs time, and therefore money. Is it going to save you more money than it costs? It's obviously impossible to really tell, but you that's what you need to work out :)

Comment: It is within my interest to finish this project as soon as possible but I don't have a budget, my budget right now is simply dictated by the time that I can spend on this project. So yes, from a minimalist point of view I can see your approach be effective. And I guess in the long run as the project will start to create revenue and I'll be able to get professional help beyond my level of expertise which is quite basic, "we will cross that bridge when we get there."